# Volume of the Solid ($2x+2$, and $x^2+2$)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have to find the volume of the solid that results when the region enclosed by the curves is revolved by the x-axis.

The problem is:

> $$y=2x+2$$
>   $$y=x^2+2$$

I simply have to setup the integral, and the integral which I think can solve the problem is:

$$\pi\int\limits_{0}^2[(2x+2)^2-(x^2+2)^2]dx$$

Comment: Where is $\pi$?

Comment: By multiplying by $\pi$ that is correct. Where are you stuck at? The resulting integral is elementary and the final outcome is $\frac{48}{5}\pi$.

Comment: @qbert I forgot the $\pi$, thanks.

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky oh well, I answered anyway since I was bored. Maybe it will help people later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close: The volume of a solid of revolution is given by 
$$
\pi \int_a^b (f(x))^2dx
$$
Where $f(x)$ gives your radius. Why? The intuitive derivation is that at each point, the area of a circular wedge is given by $\pi (f(x))^2\Delta x$, summing up over all of these guys gives you the integral above.

You have set up everything correctly but the $\pi$, you are subtracting the innermost volume since you care about the region enclosed. This also gives $a=0$ and $b=2$ since this is where the curves intersect.